# How to implement user-friends relationship in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, models, relationship

I am new to cakephp.

I am working on my Social network project.I am having users and friends relationship

concept.

I am having problem in sending friend request and accepting .....

I am not understanding how to start on this concept...

If anybody worked on such things then please help me..

Answer (score 2):

You could make a new `FriendRequest` model.

1. Give this model `belongTo User` and `hasOne Friend`.  Also, `User hasMany FriendRequest` Then, give the `FriendRequest` model a boolean field (cakePHP uses `TINYINT(1)` for boolean) to track acceptance.
2. Create a new `FriendRequest` record when a user sends a request.
3. List all `FriendRequest` records that a user has sent by searching for the ones the user `hasMany`
4. List all the `FriendRequest` records that are sent to a person by searching for all `Friend belongTo User`.
5. Change the acceptance field to `TRUE` when a User accepts the request.